# Executable has more data to send, but don't know how to signal the executable that data already sent has been processed and ready for next block

Tags: php, mysql, function, url, get

all

This is my first question ever here, so please, if I make a mistake, let me know. I want to learn all I can.

With that being said, here is my dilemma.

I am trying to modify some php so that a program used with Microsoft Flight Simulator to act as an ACARS can send a log file to my code and have that data written to a MySQL database. The program I mention breaks down the data into 1Kb chunks, sends the first bit and waits for the code to respond with OK beofre sending the next bit, and so on until all data has been retrieved and written to a file (txt) and to a database. This all works well unmodified. Here's the unmodified code;

```
@define ("MYSQL_CONNECT_INCLUDE", "connect_db.php");        // MySQL     database connection (a sample file is included)
@define ("REPORT_FILE_URL", "http://dcascreenshots.net/fsacars/logs/");             // URL where the complete FSAcars reports will be stored
@define ("REPORT_FILE_PATH", "/home/axeman65/public_html/fsacars/logs/");               // Folder where the complete FSAcars reports will be stored
@define ("ERROR_LOG_PATH", "/home/axeman65/public_html/fsacars/error.log");                 // Folder and filename where the error log is located

/*
 * Error messages */
@define ("ERROR_OPENING_REPORT_FILE","Error opening report file");
@define ("ERROR_WRITING_REPORT_FILE","Error writing report file");
@define ("PILOT_NOT_FOUND","Pilot not found");
@define ("ERROR_IN_PILOT_QUERY","Pilot query error");
@define ("ERROR_INSERTING_PIREP","Error inserting report");



function CheckFSAcarsInfo() {   
    // Verify input
    if (!isset($_GET['pilot'])) { return 0; }

    // Request is not empty
    return 1;
}

function GetFSAcarsInfo() {
/* ************************************************************************************************
   @GetFSAcarsInfo
   Receives inputs sent by FSAcars program and returns an array containing that information

   Inputs: N/A
   Outputs: string array 
   ************************************************************************************************ */

// DO NOT EDIT THIS FUNCTION - THIS FIELDS ARE SENT BY FSACARS
$fsacars_pirep = array (
    "pilot" => $_GET['pilot'],
    "date" => $_GET['date'],
    "time" => $_GET['time'],
    "callsign" => $_GET['callsign'],
    "reg" => $_GET['reg'],
    "origin" => $_GET['origin'],
    "dest" => $_GET['dest'],
    "equipment" => $_GET['equipment'],
    "fuel" => $_GET['fuel'],
    "duration" => $_GET['duration'],
    "distance" => $_GET['distance'],
    "rep_url" => "Dummy",
    "more" => $_GET['more'],
    "fsacars_log" => $_GET['log']   // Get complete FSAcars log
);

/* DEBUG CODE - Write request to log file
*/
$fe = fopen (ERROR_LOG_PATH, "a");
fwrite($fe, "[DEBUG ".date("d.m.y H:i:s")."] PILOT: ".$_GET['pilot']." DATE: ".$_GET['date']." TIME: ".$_GET['time']." CALLSIGN: ".$_GET['callsign']." REG: ".$_GET['reg']." ORIG: ".$_GET['origin']." DEST: ".$_GET['dest']." EQUIP: ".$_GET['equipment']." FUEL: ".$_GET['fuel']." DURATION: ".$_GET['duration']." DIST: ".$_GET['distance']." MORE: ".$_GET['more']." LOG: ".$_GET['log']."\n");
fclose($fe);

return $fsacars_pirep;
}

function SavePIREPFile($pirep_array) {
/* ************************************************************************************************
       @SavePIREPFile
       Receives a string array with FSAcars pireps and creates or appends information to pirep file

   Inputs: string array
   Outputs: 1 sucess, 0 error
   ************************************************************************************************ */

/* Build report filename and URL */
$filename=$pirep_array['pilot'].str_replace("/","",$pirep_array['date']).str_replace(":","",$pirep_array['time']).".txt";
$pirep_array['rep_url']=REPORT_FILE_URL.$pirep_array['pilot']."/".$filename;

/* Parse FsAcars log */
$fsacars_log_lines_array = explode("*",$pirep_array['fsacars_log']);

/* Create or Append FSAcars report file */
$fp = fopen (REPORT_FILE_PATH.$pirep_array['pilot']."/".$filename, "a");

if (!$fp) {
    /* Error opening file */
    $fe = fopen (ERROR_LOG_PATH, "a");
    fwrite($fe, "[ERROR ".date("d.m.y H:i:s")."] PILOT: ".$pirep_array['pilot']." - ".ERROR_OPENING_REPORT_FILE." - ".$filename."\n");
    fclose($fe);

    return 0;
}

/*
* Write all log lines received from FSAcars */
for($i=0;$i<count($fsacars_log_lines_array);$i++) {
        if (!fwrite($fp, $fsacars_log_lines_array[$i] . "\n")) {
            /* Error writing to file */
            $fe = fopen (ERROR_LOG_PATH, "a");
        fwrite($fe, "[ERROR ".date("d.m.y H:i:s")."] PILOT".$pirep_array['pilot']." - ".ERROR_WRITING_REPORT_FILE." - ".$filename."\n");
        fclose($fe);

            return 0;
        }
}    

/* Close file */
fclose($fp);

return 1;
}

function InsertReportIntoDB($pirep_array) {
/* ************************************************************************************************
   @InsertReportIntoDB
   Receives a string array with FSAcars pireps and inserts summary into reports table

   Inputs: string array
   Outputs: 1 sucess, 0 error
   ************************************************************************************************ */

/* If this is the first chunk insert PIREP on database */
if ($pirep_array['more']=="0") {
        /* connect to database */
        include(MYSQL_CONNECT_INCLUDE);

        /*
         * Verify pilot identity (From VA Pilots table) */
        $the_pilot = $pirep_array['pilot'];

        $stmt = "select pilot_id from fsacars_pilots where pilot_num='$the_pilot'";
        $result = mysql_query($stmt);

        /* mysql error */
        if (!$result) {
            $fe = fopen (ERROR_LOG_PATH, "a");
        fwrite($fe, "[ERROR ".date("d.m.y H:i:s")."] ".ERROR_IN_PILOT_QUERY." - Pilot ".$pirep_array['pilot']." - ".mysql_error()." SQL: ".$stmt."\n");
        fclose($fe);

        return 0;
        }

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
            /* Pilot not found */
            $fe = fopen (ERROR_LOG_PATH, "a");
        fwrite($fe, "[ERROR ".date("d.m.y H:i:s")."] ".PILOT_NOT_FOUND." - Pilot ".$pirep_array['pilot']."\n");
        fclose($fe);

        return 0;
        } else {
                /* Pilot found */
                $pilot_id = mysql_result($result,0,"pilot_id");

                /* Insert info on reports table */
                $values = $pilot_id.",'".$pirep_array['date']."','".$pirep_array['time']."','".$pirep_array['callsign']."','".$pirep_array['origin']."','".$pirep_array['dest']."','".$pirep_array['reg']."','".$pirep_array['equipment']."','".$pirep_array['duration']."',".$pirep_array['fuel'].",".$pirep_array['distance'].",'".$pirep_array['rep_url']."'";
                $stmt = "INSERT INTO reports (pilot_id,date,time,callsign,origin_id,destination_id,registration,equipment,duration,fuel,distance,fsacars_rep_url) VALUES ($values)";                    
                $result = mysql_query($stmt);

                if (!$result) {
                    $fe = fopen (ERROR_LOG_PATH, "a");
                    fwrite($fe, "[ERROR ".date("d.m.y H:i:s")."] ".ERROR_INSERTING_PIREP." - Pilot ".$pirep_array['pilot']." - ".mysql_error()." SQL: ".$stmt."\n");
                    fclose($fe);

            return 0;
            }

    /* Close the database connection */
                mysql_close();
        }
    }

    return 1;
}


function main() {
/* ************************************************************************************************
   @main

   Inputs: N/A
   Outputs: "OK" sucess, "NOTOK" error
   ************************************************************************************************ */
$res = CheckFSAcarsInfo();
if ($res == 0) {
    return "NOTOK";
}

$a = GetFSAcarsInfo();

$res = SavePIREPFile($a);
if ($res == 0) {
    return "NOTOK";
}

$res = InsertReportIntoDB($a);
if ($res == 0) {
    return "NOTOK";
}


// Report sucessfully received
return "OK";
}

/* receive_pirep.php return to FSACARS */
$out = main();
echo $out;

?>
```

The problem comes in when I add this;

```
function insertdcapirep($pirep_array) {
//  Read PIREP data from previously written file
       $filename=$pirep_array['pilot'].str_replace("/","",$pirep_array['date']).str_replace(":","",$pirep_array['time']).".txt";
$pirep_array['rep_url']=REPORT_FILE_URL.$pirep_array['pilot']."/".$filename;
$log=file(REPORT_FILE_PATH.$pirep_array['pilot']."/".$filename);

    //Find Pilot Number
    $dca = $pirep_array['pilot'];

    // Open database and pull pilot's name
    include(MYSQL_CONNECT_INCLUDE);
    $stmt="SELECT name FROM fsacars_pilots WHERE pilot_num='$dca'";
    $result=mysql_query($stmt);
    if (!$result) {
        $fe = fopen (ERROR_LOG_PATH, "a");
        fwrite($fe, "[ERROR ".date("d.m.y H:i:s")."] ".ERROR_IN_PILOT_QUERY." - Pilot ".$pirep_array['pilot']." - ".mysql_error()." SQL: ".$stmt."\n");
        fclose($fe);
        return 0;
        }
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
            $fe = fopen (ERROR_LOG_PATH, "a");
        fwrite($fe, "[ERROR ".date("d.m.y H:i:s")."] ".PILOT_NOT_FOUND." - Pilot ".$pirep_array['pilot']."\n");
        fclose($fe);
        return 0;
        } else {
        $name = mysql_result($result,0,"name");
        }
    //Find flight number
    $fltraw=explode(":",$log[1]);
    $flt=$fltraw[1];

    //find duration and convert to minutes
    $num=count($log);
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++) {
        if(stripos($log[$i],"Flight Duration")!== FALSE) {
            $duration=$log[$i];
            $total=substr($duration,-6);
            $rawtime=explode(":",$total);
            $hours=$rawtime[0]*60;
            $minutes=$hours+$rawtime[1];
    } }
    //Find Comments and save them to variable
    $num=count($log);
    for($i=0;$i<=$num;$i++) {
        if(stripos($log[$i],"comments")!== FALSE) {
        $rawcomments=strstr($log[$i],"comments");
        $almost_comments=ltrim($rawcomments,"comments");
        $comments=addslashes($almost_comments);
    } }
    // Calculate and assign date
        $timestamp=strtotime("now");    

    //Open and append data to database
    $stmt="INSERT INTO PIREPS VALUES ('',$dca,$name,$flt,$minutes,$comments,$timestamp)";
    $result=mysql_result($stmt);
    if (!$result) {
        $fe = fopen (ERROR_LOG_PATH, "a");
        fwrite($fe, "[ERROR ".date("d.m.y H:i:s")."] ".ERROR_INSERTING_PIREP." - Pilot ".$pirep_array['pilot']." - ".mysql_error()." SQL: ".$query."\n");
        fclose($fe);
        return 0;
        }
    mysql_close();
return 1;
}
```

...and add a function call under the main function, like this;

```
$res = insertdcapirep($a);
if(res==0) {
    return "NOTOK";
}
```

I know this is a lot of code, and I apologize, and if there's a better place for beginners like me to get help, I'm eager to go try there. I've been poring over this for a month, and it seems like there's something so simple, but I'm just not seeing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I fail to see what's the problem? You are getting an error? It doesn't stop? Or what should people looking to help should search for?

Comment: I'm sorry, I did neglect to mention the actual issue! The program in question is FSAcars, and it can be found at http://www.satavirtual.org/fsacars/downloads.html. The unmodified php code breaks down data received into 1KB chunks, writes it to a text file and a database. If I modify that code to include a comment and add to another table, the php stops after the first block and leaves a lot of strings empty, causing MySQL errors.

Comment: "Under the main function"? Not "inside the main function"? As a hint: try manually accessing your script e.g. through a web browser or from the command line passing the necessary parameters. See if there are any errors reported. Check the PHP error logs, if any. Also in your code the part "Open and append data to database" should use mysql_query not mysql_result.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that, lmz. I'll give that a try tomorrow, as it's late tonight and tomorrow is a work day.I'll post results...

Comment: Is there any way I can intercept the data being sent in the URLs created by FSAcars so I can check them via browser? Otherwise, I have to make a fairly lengthy flight just to check changes.

Comment: Made the change to the SQL query you pointed out, lmz, but it made no difference. I'm still getting a MySQL error because empty variables exist due to the second block of data not being received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It turns out that the entire script is cycled through every time a packet is received, with the first function actually checking if there is any content present. If not, the script stops. I was able to run my own test using

```
if(strpos($pirep[$i],"TOD Land)!==FALSE) {
include("processdcapirep.php; }
```

to check for the last line of a log file. That way, it wouldn't call my query until the entire file had been written. I appreciate every response I got. Seems like a great bunch of folks here!